# New upstream version of gnome-mplayer. How do I ask for this to be considered for release / commit?

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, mplayer, upstream

I have been using gnome-mplayer 1.0.4 with xubuntu 11.10 and it has a number of bugs. I have been reporting these on code.google.com/p/gnome-mplayer/issues/detail?id=558

Anyhow... the dev says there is a newer version 1.05 with a code rewrite which should fix some.

http://kdekorte.blogspot.com/2011/10/105b1-of-gmtk-gnome-mplayer-and-gecko.html

How do I ask for this to be considered for commit into the ubuntu repo's (testing) ?

do I just add it here...
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-mplayer

Comment: Does it fix any security issue? if not forget about it...

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read, Canonical's team is really strict about changing a working release. But the good news is that Ubuntu is never more than 6 months late: It will come out in the next release. You can manually install the newer version (from an early or Debian-specific package, or from source) while you wait.

Incidentally, I know of a program (wesnoth) which managed to find its latest version into Ubuntu's repos by making a new package. The old package (at the time) was called wesnoth, and offered version 1.6; the new program was called wesnoth-1.8.

That ensured that anyone who's depending on the bugs or features of the previous version get to keep them, while others consciously upgrade.

Comment: Development pre-releases have a less strict policy, but I assume you want the stability of the released version.